# A later version of Microsoft ASP.Net and Web Tools 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2013 is already installed. Setup will now exit

Tags: windows, azure, sdk, installation

In following the instructions located here.: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42317

for installing Windows Azure SDK for .NET -2.3

I get the error:
**A later version of Microsoft ASP.Net and Web Tools 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2013 is already installed. Setup will now exit.**

when I try to install: WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi

I removed all previous versions...eg. 2.4 and 2.5, the reboot...still no help...

To install the Windows Azure SDK for .NET manually, follow these steps:

```
Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 or Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 OR Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2012 OR Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2013.
Install LocalDB prereq of .Net FX update 4.0.2 or higher from here
Install the Windows Azure Authoring Tools - 2.3 - WindowsAzureAuthoringTools-x86.msi or WindowsAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi
Install the Windows Azure Emulator - 2.3 - WindowsAzureEmulator-x86.exe or WindowsAzureEmulator-x64.exe
Install the Windows Azure Client Libraries for .NET - 2.3 - WindowsAzureLibsForNet-x86.msi or WindowsAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi
Install the Windows Azure Storage Emulator - 2.3 - WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi
Install the Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - 2.3 - WindowsAzureTools.VS.110 or Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - 2.3 - WindowsAzureTools.VS.120
Install the Windows Azure LightSwitch Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - 2.3 - WindowsAzureTools.LightSwitch.vs120
Install the Web Tools Extensions for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi or for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 WebToolsExtensionsVS.msi or for Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2013 - WebToolsExtensionsVWD2013.msi or for Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2012 - WebToolsExtensionsVWD.msi
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?